# Set Width in WPF with DataTrigger

Tags: wpf

I have a border which contains other items (StackPanel with buttons).  I'm using a DataTrigger to try to shrink down the border when a "IsHidden" property is toggled to true.  I'm confident that the bindings are correct and the property in the DataContext is changing and the UI is being notified.  The problem is the Width property is just not being set.

Any ideas?

```
<Border Width="200" Background="{StaticResource BasicBrush}" Padding="0"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainBrush}" BorderThickness="0 10 10 0">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHidden}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the property inside style setter and it will work fine. **Local value has higher precedence order over style triggers**. So, any change in property from Style triggers won't change local value.

```
<Style>
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    .....
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can read more about it here - **[Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**.

Comment: If anyone reads this - I had the same problem, a datatrigger not working and I didn't have a local value, I had a setter just like in the answer but it was below the datatrigger, didn't think it mattered, but when I made the setter first, the datatrigger started working. So the order is important as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448098/trouble-setting-a-datatrigger-in-wpf?rq=1).  It had to do with Style precedence. I needed to move the setting of Width out of the Border element and into the style setter like below.

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource BasicBrush}" Padding="0"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainBrush}" BorderThickness="0 10 10 0">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHidden}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Comment: It's not style precedence but it's about DP value precedence. Refer to the link I posted in my answer to get clear picture of it.